# How to edit an IFrame in the IE8 Developer Tools?

Tags: iframe, ie-developer-tools, developer-tools

I would like to edit the HTML code of an IFrame in IE8 with the IE8 Developer Tools.

The  HTML tab in the Developer Tools shows the original page and the IFrame just fine. But when I click on the edit icon, only the HTML code of the original site is shown, not the code of the IFrame.

Firebug allows me to edit the IFrame. I need to do the same with the Developer Tools because I need to fix a bug in IE.

Does anybody know how to edit the content of the IFrame with the Developer Tools?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you're going to be able to do that with the edit button on the developer toolbar. I experimented with the toolbar and it seems that it likes to work with only the parent page in the 'edit' mode. Now when you click 'element source with style' next to it, you can pick up the rendered html of the child page put I'm not sure how dynamic that will be since it appears to open up in a sudo notepad view.